# Why TensorFlow's division hasn't have axis parameter?

Tags: python, math, tensorflow, linear-algebra, algebra

My problem is as follows:

When I want to divide a matrix by a vector in column axis, but TensorFlow only provides row division when `A` is a matrix with `[n,n]` shape and `v` a vector with `[1,n]` shape.

My solution was this:

```
tf.transpose(tf.div(tf.transpose(A), v))
```

<s>I tried this but it doesn't works:</s> **Update**:  It Works!

```
tf.div(A, tf.transpose(v))
```

So my question is if exists more efficient solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution with `A / tf.transpose(v)` should work. [tf.div()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/div) does not have an axis parameter because it *"Divides x / y elementwise"*. So both tensors should have the same dimensions.

In your case it works with different dimensions because [tf.div supports broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#div). More about broadcasting is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting#what_is_broadcasting).

Also it is as efficient as it could be, so no need to look for anything else.

Comment: Hi! Many Thanks for your answer. I have already corrected the mistake. It was is generated because of I define `v` as  `tf.reduce_sum(A, 1)` who returned 1D tensor so it was not transposable. Using `tf.reduce_sum(A, 1, keep_dimens=True)` it returns 2D tensor that is transposable.